# MetaData Problem: SymmetricSecurityBindingElement

Tags: wcf, metadata

I am figuring out someone else's code and I am trying to generate a proxy out of one of the services and it generates the following error...

System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension. Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.SymmetricSecurityBindingElement Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: parameters ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction. how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Its just a configuration issue. It means the Service is not configured correctly.